Concat a string adding a separator but ignoring blanks
I need to concat up to 6 fields into a single string using a separator (;) between each field.  However if the field is blank I don't want to add a separator (;) to the string.



id
myfield1
myfield2
myfield3
myfield4
myfield5
myfield6




1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1


2
-1


-1
-1
-1


3
-1
-1
-1

-1
-1



Example SQL
select 
concat(case when my_field1 = '-1' then 'Cond1; ' end, case when my_field2 = '-1' then 'Cond2; ' end, case when my_field3 = '-1' then 'Cond3; ' end, case when my_field4 = '-1' then 'Cond4; ' end, case when my_field5 = '-1' then 'Cond5; ' end, case when my_field16 = '-1' then 'Cond6' end)
as "example"
from table

The results I am getting are
Cond1; Cond2; Cond3; Cond4; Cond5; Cond6
Cond1; ; ; Cond4; Cond5; Cond6
Cond1; Cond2; Cond3; ; Cond5; Cond6

The results I want are
Cond1; Cond2; Cond3; Cond4; Cond5; Cond6
Cond1; Cond3; Cond4; Cond5; Cond6
Cond1; Cond2; Cond3; Cond5; Cond6

What do I need to change to get the correct results?

Use concat_ws perhaps? Something like: SELECT CONCAT_WS(';', NULLIF(field1, ''), ...NULLIF(fieldX, ''))

@How_K I can't reproduce your issue, see https://dbfiddle.uk/bTymA3ka. Could you please change the fiddle, so it shows your problem and share the new url?
